# Orientation in Auto-Layout

Tags: ios, storyboard, landscape

I have a iPad MainView which contains 3x Buttons each row and 2 row in view. I designed it for landscape . Now customer wants to me to Portrait orientation. Even using auto-layout, when making portrait orientation, Buttons collapsed each other ( Because they don't fit in portrait width) . I've read about auto-layout article which has scaling UI elements in order to fix it in current scene. But it does not happen to me.

What should i do in order to fix that issue ?

My buttons has ordered by landscape mode :

http://prntscr.com/36lhj7

When i rotate device to portrait in auto-layout mode, it looks like that :

http://prntscr.com/36lii4

Best Regards,

Onder OZCAN

Comment: Learn from here http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1

Comment: It is obviously auto layout issue, but we cannot help you without seeing what is going on.

Comment: @HimanshuJoshi When disabling auto-layout , App looks like mess :) I have to find a solution without disabling auto-layout issue.

Comment: @Legoless I am making screenshot for you.

Comment: @InnaKamoze using autolayout is mentioned there. Please go through the link properly

Comment: @Legoless i added screen-shot for you.

Answer (score 0):

I learned a lot from the UIView-Autolayout pod (source on [github](https://github.com/jrturton/UIView-Autolayout)). It offers all kinds of methods to make layout less painful. You can do stuff like this:

```
[self.row1 addSubview:button1];
[button1 pinEdges:JRTViewPinLeftEdge toSameEdgesOfView:self.row1];
[button1 constrainToMinimumSize:CGSizeMake(0.0, 4.0)];
[button2 pinAttribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft toAttribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft ofItem:self.button withConstant:10.0];
```

Comment: The thing is , I am using UI elements from storyboard ( IBoutlet ) . I don't think it will work on me ?

Comment: Ok,  I don't use storyboards. I get lost on autolayout issues when using storyboards. You could use the library I guess when its connected to an outlet.